# find roots with specified coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, polynomials

Please assume we have an equation which we want to obtain its roots. We can use

```
Roots[-16 x^2 (t - 2 z - 2 z y) + (t + 2 z + 
  2 z y) ((-4 + t - 2 z) (4 + t - 2 z) - 4 z^2 y^2) == 0, t]
```

in order to access its roots. We encounter to answers as

```
-(2/3) (-z + 
y z) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-48 - 48 x^2 - 16 z^2 - 16 y z^2 - 
  16 y^2 z^2))/(3 2^(
2/3) (1152 z - 576 x^2 z + 576 y z - 1152 x^2 y z - 128 z^3 - 
  192 y z^3 + 192 y^2 z^3 + 128 y^3 z^3 + Sqrt[
  4 (-48 - 48 x^2 - 16 z^2 - 16 y z^2 - 16 y^2 z^2)^3 + (1152 z - 
     576 x^2 z + 576 y z - 1152 x^2 y z - 128 z^3 - 192 y z^3 + 
     192 y^2 z^3 + 128 y^3 z^3)^2])^(1/3)) - (1/(
6 2^(1/3)))(1 - I Sqrt[3]) (1152 z - 576 x^2 z + 576 y z - 
1152 x^2 y z - 128 z^3 - 192 y z^3 + 192 y^2 z^3 + 128 y^3 z^3 + 
Sqrt[4 (-48 - 48 x^2 - 16 z^2 - 16 y z^2 - 
    16 y^2 z^2)^3 + (1152 z - 576 x^2 z + 576 y z - 
   1152 x^2 y z - 128 z^3 - 192 y z^3 + 192 y^2 z^3 + 
   128 y^3 z^3)^2])^(1/3)
```

in which there is a term as `(1 + I Sqrt[3])` and `(1 - I Sqrt[3])`. But when we use

```
Plot[-16 x^2 (t - 2 z - 2 z y) + (t + 2 z + 
  2 z y) ((-4 + t - 2 z) (4 + t - 2 z) - 4 z^2 y^2) /. {x -> 1, 
  y -> 0.5, z -> 1}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

we see there are three roots.

[image]

It means the imaginary parts in roots are not important albeit {x -> 1, 
      y -> 0.5, z -> 1}. 
In my case x, y and z are in [0,1]. For this reason we can we have three real roots.

With the condition which is governed on the coefficients (x, y and z) that must be in [0,1], how can we obtain the real configuration of the roots of the main equation? ( for example an equation as a root without an imaginary part)

Comment: If you want roots extressed as radicals, that cannot be done. Check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis) for further detail. If you are looking for conditions on `{x,y,z}` for which the real root count switches between 1 and 3, that's a whole different matter. You'd want to read up on discriminants, I think.

Comment: You can't generally express the roots of a depressed cubic via radicals without using complex numbers. That's mathematics, sorry.

Comment: @ Daniel,No I don't want to find roots in a special interval. the coefficient of polynomial is in an intervals that roots are real and imaginary parts are eliminated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited to provide general analytical answer.**

With,

```
f = -16 x^2 (t - 2 z - 2 z y) + (t + 2 z + 2 z y) ((-4 + t - 2 z) (4 + t - 2 z)
    - 4 z^2 y^2);
```

the `Discriminant` of this cubic in `t` is

```
d = Discriminant[f, t] // Factor

(* 4096 (4 + 12 x^2 + 12 x^4 + 4 x^6 - 8 z^2 + 20 x^2 z^2 + x^4 z^2 - 8 y z^2 + 
   38 x^2 y z^2 - 8 x^4 y z^2 + y^2 z^2 + 20 x^2 y^2 z^2 - 8 x^4 y^2 z^2 + 4 z^4 + 
   8 y z^4 - 2 x^2 y z^4 + 2 y^2 z^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 z^4 - 2 y^3 z^4 + 8 x^2 y^3 z^4 + 
   4 x^2 y^4 z^4 + y^2 z^6 + 2 y^3 z^6 + y^4 z^6) *)
```

`FindInstance` suggests that `d` is non-negative everywhere,

```
FindInstance[d < 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]
(* {} *)
```

as does random sampling of points `{x, y, z}`.  On this basis, it seems safe to conclude the roots of `f`, too lengthy to reproduce here,

```
rt = t /. Solve[f == 0, t]
```

are real, despite the fact that `I` appears in the `rt[[2]]` and `rt[[3]]`, just as observed in the question.  As a further test, `Im[rt[[2]]]` for several slices in, for instance, `x`.

```
Plot3D[Table[Im[rt[[2]]] // Chop, {x, -5, 5}], {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
    PlotRange -> {-10^-8, 10^-8}]
```

is zero everywhere, again substantiating that all `rt` are real.

The general solution, based on 3.8.2 of Abramowitz and Stegun, is derived as follows.

```
a = CoefficientList[f, t]
(* {-32 z + 32 x^2 z - 32 y z + 32 x^2 y z + 8 z^3 + 8 y z^3 - 
    8 y^2 z^3 - 8 y^3 z^3, -16 - 16 x^2 - 4 z^2 - 8 y z^2 - 4 y^2 z^2, -2 z + 2 y z, 1} *)

q = Simplify[a[[2]]/3 - a[[3]]^2/9]
(* -(16/9) (3 + 3 x^2 + (1 + y + y^2) z^2) *)
r = Simplify[(a[[2]] a[[3]] - 3 a[[1]])/6 - a[[3]]^3/27]
(* 32/27 z (-9 x^2 (1 + 2 y) + (2 + y) (9 + (-1 - y + 2 y^2) z^2)) *)
Factor[q^3 + r^2];
```

The last expression is proportional to the negative of `d` and, therefore, is non-positive.  We can then write the key expression,

```
s = ComplexExpand[(r + I Sqrt[-q^3 - r^2])^(1/3), TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
```

which, after a bit of additional manipulation becomes

```
(* (c1 + c2^2)^(1/6) Cos[1/3 ArcTan[c2, Sqrt[c1]]] + 
   I (c1 + c2^2)^(1/6) Sin[1/3 ArcTan[c2, Sqrt[c1]]] *)
```

where

```
rul = {c1 -> (4096/729 (3 + 3 x^2 + (1 + y + y^2) z^2)^3 - 1024/729 z^2 (-9 x^2 (1 + 2 y) 
           + (2 + y) (9 + (-1 - y + 2 y^2) z^2))^2), 
       c2 -> 32/27 z (-9 x^2 (1 + 2 y) + (2 + y) (9 + (-1 - y + 2 y^2) z^2))}
```

The roots of `f` are, then,

```
re = {2 s[[1]] - a[[3]]/3, -s[[1]] + I s[[2]] Sqrt[3] - a[[3]]/3, 
    -s[[1]] - I s[[2]] Sqrt[3] - a[[3]]/3} // Simplify
(* {2/3 (z - y z + 3 (c1 + c2^2)^(1/6) Cos[1/3 ArcTan[c2, Sqrt[c1]]]), 
    1/3 (-2 (-1 + y) z - 3 (c1 + c2^2)^(1/6) Cos[1/3 ArcTan[c2, Sqrt[c1]]] - 
        3 Sqrt[3] (c1 + c2^2)^(1/6) Sin[1/3 ArcTan[c2, Sqrt[c1]]]), 
    -(2/3) (-1 + y) z - (c1 + c2^2)^(1/6) Cos[1/3 ArcTan[c2, Sqrt[c1]]] + 
        Sqrt[3] (c1 + c2^2)^(1/6) Sin[1/3 ArcTan[c2, Sqrt[c1]]]} *)
```

which explicitly answers the question posed by the OP.  That this is equivalent to the solutions `rt`, two of which do contain `I` explicitly, can be seen from, for instance,

```
re /. rul /. {x -> 1, y -> 0.5, z -> 1}
(* {6.81903, -6.03763, 0.218601} *)
rt /. {x -> 1, y -> 0.5, z -> 1}
(* {6.81903 - 4.44089*10^-16 I, -6.03763 - 6.66134*10^-16 I, 0.218601 + 1.33227*10^-15 I}*)
```

or, if exact values are desired,

```
re /. rul /. {x -> 1, y -> 1/2, z -> 1}
(* {1/3 (1 + 4 Sqrt[31] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]]), 
    1/3 (1 - 2 Sqrt[31] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]] - 
        2 Sqrt[93] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]]), 
    1/3 (1 - 2 Sqrt[31] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]] + 
        2 Sqrt[93] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]])} *)

ComplexExpand[Simplify[rt /. {x -> 1, y -> 1/2, z -> 1}]] // FullSimplify
```

produces the same answer.

Comment: Your explanation clarifies more things.

Answer (score 5):

```
roots = t /. {Roots[-16 x^2 (t - 2 z - 2 z y) + (t + 2 z + 
            2 z y) ((-4 + t - 2 z) (4 + t - 2 z) - 4 z^2 y^2) == 0, t] // 
      ToRules} // Simplify;

roots // LeafCount

(*  861  *)
```

To get a representation without `I` use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
roots2 = ComplexExpand[roots, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify;

roots2 // LeafCount

(*  25973  *)
```

The first representation using `I` is much less complicated.

For your specific example,

```
ex1 = roots /. {x -> 1, y -> 1/2, z -> 1} // FullSimplify

(*  {Root[9 - 41 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
 Root[9 - 41 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 Root[9 - 41 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]}  *)

ans1 = ex1 // N

(*  {6.81903, -6.03763, 0.218601}  *)
```

Converting the [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions

```
ex1R = ex1 // ToRadicals // ComplexExpand // Simplify

(*  {1/3 (1 + 4 Sqrt[31] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]]), 
 1/3 (1 - 2 Sqrt[31] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]] - 
    2 Sqrt[93] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]]), 
 1/3 (1 - 2 Sqrt[31] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]] + 
    2 Sqrt[93] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[367])/8]])}  *)
```

For the second form

```
ex2 = roots2 /. {x -> 1, y -> 1/2, z -> 1} // FullSimplify

(*  {(1/3)*(1 + 4*Sqrt[31]*
          Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[(9*Sqrt[367])/
                  8]]), (1/3)*
     (1 - 2*Sqrt[31]*
          Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[(9*Sqrt[367])/
                  8]] - 2*Sqrt[93]*
          Sin[(1/3)*ArcTan[(9*Sqrt[367])/
                  8]]), (1/3)*
     (1 - 2*Sqrt[31]*
          Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[(9*Sqrt[367])/
                  8]] + 2*Sqrt[93]*
          Sin[(1/3)*ArcTan[(9*Sqrt[367])/
                  8]])}  *)
```

This is identical to earlier result

```
ex2 === ex1R

(*  True  *)
```

Demonstrating that the original `Root` expression is equivalent

```
(ex2 // N) == ans1

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: It is so amazing!